# Backspace and space in smartphone are selecting copying and pasting the last word

Tags: mobile, angular7, ionic4, document, contenteditable

I have a div with the contentEditable attribute set to true, and this div works as a input of my app and when i type a @ or a $ its possible to mark peoples

When i mark someone, the name of that person is going to be added inside an span with a class and some more attributes, and then it will be append to the parent div with contentEditable.

This works well in the web.

The problem is: In the smartphone when do this, and after the person is marked,
i press space and the last word is copied and pasted instead of just a space, and then when i type backspace repeatedly it has the same behavior, copying and pasting several times, this is worst when i use the motorola keyboard

[Here is the structure of the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PauFz.png)

[And here is the visual thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op3yq.png)